# AppOffline rule issue w/ Continuous Integration/Build

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, newrelic, azure-devops

I've connected Visual Studio Team Services to an Azure Website to enable automatic deployments. New Relic is running as a system process and therefore `NewRelic.Agent.Core.dll` is locked which prevents successful builds from being deployed.

I've tried adding a wpp.targets file to the solution in order to utilize MSDeploy to copy an app_offline document to the site before deployment, then delete it when deployment is done like seen [here](http://sedodream.com/2012/01/08/HowToTakeYourWebAppOfflineDuringPublishing.aspx).  However, it doesn't seem as if it is executing.  I don't see anything in the build logs and my deployments continue to fail.

How do I take the app offline when using the VS Team Services/Azure CI process?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this old post and there are now build tasks to start and stop an app service. See the `Azure App Service Manage` under the deployment tasks in the [build task catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/#Deploy).

Answer (score -1):

Slightly different to what you are asking but what you could do is to login to your Azure website and set `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` to 0 before your build runs. You then deploy as normal. Once done you set `COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` back to 1.

The act of changing the setting will cause an IIS reset and setting it to zero will disable the file from being locked again before the publish finishes.

Source: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/visual-studio-online-azure-website-continuous-integration-fails/3825